# Read/write Jupyter notebook for myself, read-only for others

Tags: jupyterhub

I have just setup TLJH (The Littlest JupyterHub) and am planning to use it to have read/write access for my (admin) notebooks and read-only access with other (non-admin) users.

I have tried to follow this guide: https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/howto/content/share-data.html

I am logged in as an Admin user and performed the following:

1. Created a shared folder 
   `sudo mkdir -p /srv/sharedFolder`
2. cd into skeleton directory
   `cd /etc/skel`
3. Add symbolic link for new users to access the folder
   `sudo ln -s /srv/sharedfolder sharedFolder`
4. Create Jupyter notebook in my home directory `/home/myUserName/myNotebook.ipynb`
5. Copy into `/srv/sharedFolder` `cp /home/myUserName/myNotebook.ipynb /srv/sharedFolder`
6. Create new user from control panel
7. Log in as new user

The new user has read-only access to `myNotebook.ipynb`.

However, I (admin) am unable to edit the notebook as it resides in `/srv/sharedFolder` which belongs to root.

I would like to avoid manually removing `rm` and copying `cp` the notebook to the shared folder every time I make any changes.

I have thought of:

1. Create shared folder without sudo in current user directory `mkdir -p ~/myUserName/sharedFolder`
2. cd into skeleton directory
   `cd /etc/skel`
3. Add symbolic link
   `sudo ln -s ~/myUserName/sharedFolder sharedFolder`

The new user cannot see the `myNotebook.ipynb`.

I have also tried changing the notebook's permissions with `sudo chmod 644 myNotebook.ipynb`.

Would appreciate any help possible, thank you